# Cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [11]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: c++

I am making a program in C++ that creates a `.bmp` file, but I am getting an error I don't understand:

> 'HANDLE CreateFileW(LPCWSTR,DWORD,DWORD,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,DWORD,DWORD,HANDLE)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [11]' to 'LPCWSTR'

This error happens when I compile this code:

```
file = CreateFile("exmple.bmp", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Comment: This is not a useful title. Please correct it.

Comment: I correct please correct your vote.

Comment: Nope, still not useful.

Comment: Now Remy Lebeau edited my question. Can you improve your vote?

Comment: The title is better now but still this question is not likely to be useful for others in the future.

Comment: Maybe you tell me the title appropriate?

Comment: As I said, the title is better, but the question is not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put a 'L' in front of the "example.bmp" string, e.g:

   ```
   file = CreateFile(L"exmple.bmp",GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
   ```
2. This transforms "example.bmp" into a wide-character string.

Answer (score 6):

You are compiling with `UNICODE` enabled, so `CreateFile()` maps to `CreateFileW()`, and its first argument is a `LPCWSTR`, a pointer to a 16-bit (wide-character) string.

To fix the error, add `L` to the front of your string literal to make it a wide string:

```
file = CreateFile(L"exmple.bmp", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Comment: Or – assuming that you don't need wide characters – call the ANSI variant of CreateFile named `CreateFileA`.

Answer (score 2):

You need add 'L' before the name of file.