# Cannot convert const char[16] to LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to play a .wav file in the background but I am getting two errors that state:

> argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

and another error that states:

> 'BOOL PlaySoundW(LPCWSTR,HMODULE,DWORD)':cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char[16]'to 'LPCWSTR'

I can play sound using `PlaySound(TEXT("Totalrecall.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP);`  but I am getting errors when I try to play it in the background and loop it using `PlaySound("Totalrecall.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC);`

Comment: Look at what is different between those calls, and what the error message is.

Comment: Yes but I do not understand what the error messages mean. I stated them in my question in the first paragraph

Comment: In one you call it with `TEXT(string)` and the other you just pass `string` - what do you think the `TEXT` macro does?

Comment: You don't seem to be asking how to convert, you seem to be asking why your first function call works, but the second one produces compiler errors. Please clarify what exactly you're asking.

Comment: @Tas That might be my fault. I changed the title to be the error, because the previous one was something like "playing sound doesn't work" which was incredibly vague.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char \[11\]' to 'LPCWSTR'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551000/cannot-convert-argument-1-from-const-char-11-to-lpcwstr)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert parameter from 'const char\[20\]' to 'LPCWSTR'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481378/cannot-convert-parameter-from-const-char20-to-lpcwstr)

Answer (score 3):

`PlaySound()` without an `A` or `W` suffix maps to either `PlaySoundW()` or `PlaySoundA()`, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.  This variant of `PlaySound()` takes an `LPCTSTR` (`const TCHAR*`) as input.

`TCHAR` maps to either `wchar_t` or `char`, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.

`TEXT()` maps a compile-time string/char  literal to either `const wchar_t[]`/`wchar_t` or `const char[]`/`char`, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.

Since the error messages are complaining about `PlaySoundW` and `LPCWSTR`, you are clearly compiling your project with Unicode enabled, where the `UNICODE` conditional is defined.

But you are trying to pass a narrow `const char[]` string literal where a wide `wchar_t*` string is expected, so you get compiler errors.

Calling `PlaySound(TEXT("Totalrecall.wav"), ...)` will always compile fine - it would be calling `PlaySoundW(L"Totalrecall.wav", ...)` when `UNICODE` is defined, and `PlaySoundA("Totalrecall.wav", ...)` when not defined.

But calling `PlaySound("Totalrecall.wav", ...)` will compile only when `UNICODE` is NOT defined.

That being said, if you want to pass a narrow string unconditionally, especially if it is a runtime variable, use `PlaySoundA()` directly:

```
PlaySoundA("Totalrecall.wav", ...)
```

If you want to pass a wide string unconditionally, especially if it is a runtime variable, use `PlaySoundW()` directly:

```
PlaySoundW(L"Totalrecall.wav", ...)
```

Otherwise, use `TEXT()` with `PlaySound()` generically (but only for compile-time string literals):

```
PlaySound(TEXT("Totalrecall.wav"), ...)
```

Most Win32 API functions and structures that deal with string data operate in this manner, providing separate `A` and `W` variants and using preprocessor macros to map `TCHAR`-based code to one or the other.  Only newer APIs introduced in the past few years are strictly Unicode-only and do not provide ANSI variants.